# How to get a list of custom objects from Rust to Python with Ctypes?

Tags: python, rust, ctypes, ffi

I am trying to send an array of custom objects from Rust to Python as a result of a function call:

```
pub struct Item {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    tags: Vec<String>
}

pub struct SearchResults {
    count: usize,
    results: Vec<Item>
}

fn get_content(url: &str) -> hyper::Result<String> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let mut response = try!(client.get(url).send());
    let mut buf = String::new();
    try!(response.read_to_string(&mut buf));
    Ok(buf)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn get_search_results(search: &str) -> SearchResults {

    let mut url = String::from("http://localhost:8080/search?q=");
    url.push_str(&search);

    let content = get_content(&url).unwrap();
    let j: Vec<SearchResult> = json::decode(&content).unwrap();
    return SearchResults {count: j.len(), results: j};
}
```

And my Python code:

```py
from ctypes import cdll, Structure, c_wchar_p, c_int, POINTER


class SearchResult(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("name", c_wchar_p), ("description", c_wchar_p), ("tags", POINTER(c_wchar_p))]


class SearchResults(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("count", c_int), ("results", POINTER(SearchResult))]

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("target/release/libplugin_core.dylib")

get_search_results = lib.get_search_results
get_search_results.restype = SearchResults

print(get_search_results("test"))
```

When I run the Python code I get a malloc exception:

```
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=140734736883712) failed (error code=3)
```

Probably missing a bunch of stuff in there.

Comment: `&str` and `Result` or `Vec` are not ffi-safe types.

Comment: You may wish to check out [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/). While I don't currently have returning a collection of items, there's lot's simpler things that you need to do before that point.

Comment: Looks super useful, thx !